# convert char[] to __be16 type in linux kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to convert a char[] to __be16 type in linux kernel space.

I can able to convert char[] to int using `kstrtoint`. The same function works for __be16 too, but with warnings. Similarly any predefined functions available for __be16 too?

Example :

char x[120] = "02" to __be16 xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__be16` actually is a `network short int`, so you can use `htons` function:

```
char* str = "123"; // input
int val;
__be16 nval; // output

kstrtoint(str, 10, &val);
nval = htons(val);
```

Also, `cpu_to_be16` can be used instead of `htons`.

Comment: I used both htons and cpu_to_be_16 as mentioned. But I'm getting other values when printed using printk("be16 = %d\n",val); For "01", the printed value is 256

Comment: `__be16` uses byteorder, differed from one of CPU, so it cannot be printed directly. Such types (`__be*`) are usually used for transfer data between different machines. Sender uses `hton*` for convert native value into this format, receiver uses `ntoh*` for convert from this format into native value: `printk("be16 = %d\n", ntohs(val));`.